# scaling eigenvalues in matrix A (state space form)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, control-theory

A have matrix A. The values and eigenvalues are:

```
1.0000    0.0500         0         0         0
     0    0.9248    0.2489         0         0
     0   -0.0179    0.9998         0         0
     0         0         0    1.0000         0
     0         0         0         0    1.0000
```

end

```
1.0000
0.9623 + 0.0551i
0.9623 - 0.0551i
1.0000
1.0000
```

This matrix is matrix A for linear discrite time system in state space 
form:

```
x(k+1) = A*x(k) + B*u(k)
y(k) = C*x(k)
```

I use linear matrix inequality to design observer for state estimation. The problem is that my problem to solve is infeasible. However if I multiply the matrix A by 0.9 then eigenvalues are

```
0.9000
0.8660 + 0.0496i
0.8660 - 0.0496i
0.9000          
0.9000
```

No my problem is feasible. Can I scale matrix A? More precisely, can I scale eigenvalues in matrix A to obtain eigenvalues las then 1 ?

Comment: Why do you want to use LMI's in the first place? Can't you use pole placement or Kalman filter?

Comment: I minimize Hinf and H2 norm in the form of LMIs using Matlab and yalmip.If I remove the LMIs for H2 norm and leave only LMIs Hinf problem is the same. My problem is ill conditioned.

Comment: You cannot scale $A$. Your problem depends on $C$ matrix. If your system is not detectable, then it is ill-conditioned and you cannot do anything about it.

Comment: This is very bad information for my....